# Why Dataset does not accept to add two more lines in an element?

Tags: dataset, interface

Why Dataset does not accept to add two more lines in the "quantifying" element (and returns an Association instead of making the 2 more lines)?

```
Dataset[
 {
  Association[
   "Workflow" ->
    Association[

     "modeling" ->
      Association[
       "binarizing" -> binarizing,
       "quantifying" -> Association[
         "framing" -> framing,
         "deriving" -> deriving
         ]
       ],

     "simulating" ->
      Association[
       "decomposing" -> decomposing,
       "transforming" -> transforming
       ],

     "governing" ->
      Association[
       "testing" -> testing,
       "observing" -> observing,
       "controling" -> controling,
       "solving" -> solving

       ]
     ]
   ]},
 ItemSize -> {Automatic}
 ]
```